# VSCode extension authoring get all exports from a file

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to build a vscode extension which tries to parse all the exports from a particular file given its path. Is there any way to do this other than parse all the text in the file and explicitly look for the occurrence of the word 'export'. 
If not is there any way I can get all the exported symbols in my current project directory.

The extension should work for ES5, ES6, and Typescript

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language are you targeting?

Comment: @MattBierner ES5, ES6 and typescript